# Selecting all records from a table by querying a JSON column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I want to select all the records in a table by querying a specific column which stores a JSON in string format.

The query should match only the values (not keys) of the JSON string by checking if it contains a text.

The JSON in the column might look like the following for two different records:

```js
{
  "title": "Test Coupon for Test Data Initializer",
  "value": "$100",
  "tag": "Test Coupon",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "expire": "10",
  "disclaimer": "NOT VALID"
}

{
  "title": "Second Record",
  "value": "$40",
  "tag": "Initializer",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "expire": "25",
  "disclaimer": "Disclaimer"
}
```

I want to query all the values of the JSON in this column which will match or contain a text and return the records which have found a match.

For e.g. if I send the text "Initializer", it should see that the first JSON contains "Initializer" in `title` and the second JSON contains it in `tag`. Therefore both records must be returned

I'm not too familiar with the SQL JSON functions and this is what I have so far (not working)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.*') = '%Initializer%'
```

Comment: Which database system (and version of that database system) are you using?

Comment: MSQL Server (version 15.0 0.4188). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You mean SQL Server 2019, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have created a Data Source (Microsoft SQL Server) on IntelliJ. How do I find out the version of the database system?

Comment: The driver is this Microsoft JDBC Driver 9.4 for SQL Server (ver. 9.4.0.0, JDBC.2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(t.json_column)
    WHERE value LIKE N'%initializer%'
)
```

Comment: Hello, would you be able to help me in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411130/querying-json-key-with-values-as-json-in-sql-server