# Querying JSON key with values as JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nosql, ssms

I have these `JSON`:

```
Application 1:

{
"business_industry": "Agriculture",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "type": "Asset & Liability Statement"
    },
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"quote": {
    "principal": 0,
    "short_id": "3856545"
}
}

Application 2:

{
"business_industry": "Construction",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"asset": {
    "model": null,
    "make": "3856545"
}
}

Application 3:

{
"business_industry": "Coal Mining",
"business_business_names": [
    {
    "business_organisation_name": "Centron Consulting Services",
    "business_effective_from": "2018-04-11"
    }
],
"lite_doc": {
    "total_sales": 0,
    "total_sales2": 0,
    "refunds_present": false,
    "payment_arrangement_evident": false
}
}
```

which are derived from `DataReceived` in my `Application` model.

I would like to query all applications and get the keys with objects as values.

Something like:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   docs   | quotes    | asset | business_business_names    | lite_doc                    |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| internal | principal | model | business_organisation_name | total_sales                 |
| type     | short_id  | make  | business_effective_from    | total_sales2                |
| name     |           |       |                            | refunds_present             |
|          |           |       |                            | payment_arrangement_evident |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

This code is currently what I have:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
SELECT
    asset.[key] AS asset
FROM dbo.Application
-- SELECT ALL KEYS THAT HAVE OBJECTS AS VALUES AND DISPLAY THOSE OBJECTS' KEYS
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DataReceived, '$.asset') AS asset;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Do nothing 
END CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

But it can only query the `asset` and it's not `DISTINCT`.

[image]

For some reason `DISTINCT` does not work in the query.

[image]

How do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Is this SQL server? If so, edit the tags please.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, it is. I've added the tags

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code

```
BEGIN TRY

SELECT DISTINCT
    key, value.*
FROM dbo.Application
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DataReceived) AS value WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND JSON_TYPE(value) = 'object';

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Do nothing 
END CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

1. Adding select distinct will select distinct keys from dbo.Application.
   2)OPENJSON function is used to parse the (DataReceived) column with different value for each key.

Comment: Hello, it says incorrect syntax on 'key' and 'JSON_TYPE' is not a recongnized built-in function